# Error about std::promise in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, return-value, std, promise

I am trying to pass my class instance into threads and the return the processed objects from threads. I've googled about C++ multithreading, and found that std::promising can be helpful.

However, I am stuck at the very beginning. Here is my code:

```
void callerFunc()
{
    //...
    std::promise<DataWareHouse> data_chunks;    
    // DataWareHouse is my customized class
    //data_chunks has a vector<vector<double>> member variable
    std::thread(&run_thread,data_chunks);
    // ............
}

void run_thread(std::promise<DataWareHouse> data_chunks)
{
    // ... 
    vector<vector<double>> results;
    // ...
    data_chunks.set_value(results);
}
```

The above code generates an error:

```
 `error C2248: 'std::promise<_Ty>::promise' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::promise<_Ty>'`
```

May I know what am I wrong and how to fix it?

Many thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you are using `std::thread` -- `std::thread` is a low level class which you should build higher abstractions up on.  Threading is newly standardized in C++ in C++11, and all of the rough parts are not filed off yet.

There are three different patterns for using threading in C++11 that might be useful to you.

First, `std::async`.  Second, `std::thread` mixed with `std::packaged_task`.  And third, dealing with `std::thread` and `std::promise` in the raw.

I'll illustrate the third, which is the lowest level and most dangerous, because that is what you asked for.  I would advise looking at the first two options.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<double> DataWareHouse;

void run_thread(std::promise<DataWareHouse> data_chunks)
{
  DataWareHouse results;
  results.push_back( 3.14159 );
  data_chunks.set_value(results);
}

std::future<DataWareHouse> do_async_work()
{
  std::promise<DataWareHouse> data_chunks;  
  std::future<DataWareHouse> retval = data_chunks.get_future();
  // DataWareHouse is my customized class
  //data_chunks has a vector<vector<double>> member variable
  std::thread t = std::thread(&run_thread,std::move(data_chunks));
  t.detach(); // do this or seg fault
  return retval;
}

int main() {
  std::future<DataWareHouse> result = do_async_work();
  DataWareHouse vec = result.get(); // block and get the data
  for (double d: vec) {
    std::cout << d << "\n";
  }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=be55ddd793fc3d1fdef68014668b2e88-4f34a5fd633ef9f45cb08f8e23efae0a)

With `std::async`, you'd have a function returning `DataWareHouse`, and it would return a `std::future<DataWareHouse>` directly.

With `std::packaged_task<>`, it would take your `run_thread` and turn it into a `packaged_task` that can be executed, and a `std::future` extracted from it.

Answer (score 2):

`std::promise<>` is not copyable, and in calling `run_thread()` you are implicitly trying to invoke the copy constructor.  The error message is telling you that you cannot use the copy constructor since it is marked private.

You need to pass a promise by reference (`std::promise<DataWareHouse> &`).  This is safe if `callerFunc()` is guaranteed not to return until `run_thread()` is finished with the object (otherwise you will be using a reference to a destroyed stack-allocated object, and I don't have to explain why that's bad).

Comment: @Yakk: The caller needs to access the promise later, to receive the results. It couldn't do that if it had been moved into the thread.

Comment: @MikeSeymour why not extract a `std::future` from the `std::promise`, then `move` the `std::promise` into the thread?  This gets rid of the nasty reference-shared-with-thread problem.

Comment: @Yakk: Why not indeed? That would be a better answer than mine. Although it might be even better to use `std::async`, rather than reimplementing it...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass the promise to the thread by value; but you need to pass by reference to get the results back to the caller's promise. `std::promise` is uncopyable, to prevent this mistake.

```
std::thread(&run_thread,std::ref(data_chunks));
                        ^^^^^^^^

void run_thread(std::promise<DataWareHouse> & data_chunks)
                                            ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you you cannot copy an `std::promise`, which you do here:

```
void run_thread(std::promise<DataWareHouse> data_chunks)
```

and here:

```
std::thread(&run_thread,data_chunks); // makes copy of data_chunks
```

You should pass a reference:

```
void run_thread(std::promise<DataWareHouse>& data_chunks);
//                                         ^
```

And then pass an `std::reference_wrapper` to the thread, otherwise it too will attempt to copy the promise. This is easily done with `std::ref`:

```
std::thread(&run_thread, std::ref(data_chunks));
//                       ^^^^^^^^
```

Obviously `data_chunks` must be alive until the thread finished running, so you will have to join the thread in `callerFunc()`.